# Why am I getting a" Run time Error '13': Type Mismatch" error message?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am very new to VBA and still learning programming languages and coding. I came up with the following code for my project after reffering several online tutorials and threads. When I run the code I get an error message saying,Run-time Error: Type mismatch.If anyone of you experts could help me to find the error, it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance

```
Dim wsServiceRegistry As Worksheet, wsInhouseMaterialInventory As Worksheet
Dim updateCell As Range
Dim emptyRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsServiceRegistry = .Worksheets("Service Registry")
    Set wsInhouseMaterialInventory = .Worksheets("Inhouse Material Inventory")
End With

Set updateCell = wsInhouseMaterialInventory.Cells(Me.InhouseMaterialComboBox.ListIndex + 2, 4)
updateCell.Value = updateCell.Value - Val(Me.MaterialQuantityTextBox.Value)


If updateCell.Value < 1 Then updateCell.EntireRow.Delete: Exit Sub
```

Comment: You should declare `updateCell` as `Range`, not `Long`.

Comment: Thanks Rory for taking your valubale time to help me. Now, Compile error issue is resolves, but I get an error saying " Run-time error'13' Type mismatch. If you could help me to get rid of this error, its highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: I changed the code following the suggetion.

Comment: what line does arise the error?

Comment: What is the current value of the `updateCell` and what text is in `MaterialQuantityTextBox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only line that can cause a type mismatch here is
`updateCell.Value = updateCell.Value - Val(Me.MaterialQuantityTextBox.Value)`
, depending on what the cell contains.

The first thing to find out, is if it is the cell you actually want and if it contains what you expect. Add these lines just above the line in question:

```
Debug.Print updateCell.Address
Debug.Print updateCell.Value
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to show the debug output and run it. If the output matches your expectation, then you'll have to use the `Val` function again, like this:

```
updateCell.Value = Val(updateCell.Value) - Val(Me.MaterialQuantityTextBox.Value)
```

forcing the `updateCell` to become something you can subtract from.